# CorePropertyManager.Create(true) and CorePropertyManager.Create(False)

Tags: sharepoint-server

New to SharePoint and was confused by the CorePropertyManager.Create(isSection) method.  What does it actually mean when you say a CoreProperty object is section?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get the answer you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property provides backward compatibility for older custom solutions. For new custom solutions created for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 , use CoreProperty, ProfileTypeProperty, and ProfileSubtypeProperty, which provide more granular control over user profile properties.

**There are two types of user profile core properties:**

- **Regular**.Defines the core property data type and the corresponding user profile flags.
- **Section**.Core property that serves as a separator for user interface grouping purposes.

Because of the nature of the Section type, the following properties are not applicable to it: Type, Length, IsMultivalued, IsAlias, IsSearchable, and Separator. If you try to set a value, an UpdateReadOnlyFieldException is thrown.

For regular properties, the Name, Type, Length, and IsMultivalued properties can only be set at creation time. No further update is allowed. If there is an attempt to update, an UpdateReadOnlyFieldException is thrown. The Name property is used to compose the URI of the property. Therefore the name must be a valid URI schema name, otherwise an InvalidValueException is thrown.

Please Check the same details at below URL.

[CoreProperty class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.coreproperty.aspx)

**Note:-**

Any specific property set contains "A profile subtype property" and "its associated core" and "profile type properties".

Changing these properties affects all instances of this property set.